# Socket blocked in transmitting json object from Java to Python

Tags: java, android, python, json, sockets

I have a problem with a Java-Python Socket. My objective is to send a Json object from java application to python script via socket tcp and receive a response but the socket is blocked after Json sending. In the following there is my code:

```
try {
    Socket socket = new Socket(dstAddress, dstPort);
    is = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    os = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(os, true);
    pw.println(jsonObject.toString());
    System.out.println("Send to the socket jsonObject.");

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    String response = in.readLine();
    System.out.println("Response: " + response);
    is.close();
    os.close();


} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

In  the following lines the python code:

```
HOST = "192.168.1.101" #localhost
PORT = 7011
s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(1)

while (1):
    print("\n\nAttending for client.....\n\n")
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print("Connected by: " , addr) 

    data = ""
    while 1:
        temp = conn.recv(1024).decode()
        if not temp:
            break
        data = data + temp

    print("JSON Received!!!!!")

    imageJson = {}
    imageJson = json.loads(data)

    # responding to the client 
    response = DbImages[elem[0]]

    resp = "Prova"
    conn.send(resp.encode())
```

If I terminate the java code (ctrl+C) the socket exit from block and json arrive to python. What is the problem? The problem seems to be in.readLine (). If I delete that statement then the socket works without blocks.

Answer (score 1):

Your Python code is waiting for the Java side to finish and send EOF before responding (that’s what it means to `recv` until you get an empty bytes).

Your Java code is waiting for the Python side to respond before closing the socket.

So, they’re both waiting for each other.

---

Removing the `readLine` means the Java code is no longer waiting for anything, so it just hangs up on the Python code as soon as it’s done sending, which does make the problem go away—but it isn’t much of a solution if you actually needed a response.

---

So, what should they be doing? Well, there are a few different options.

- Use a framed protocol, where the Java side either sends a “message-done” delimiter after each message or sends a header (with, e.g., the byte length of the message) before each one. So, the Python code can read until it has a complete message, instead of until EOF.

  - If you encode your JSON in compact format with everything but printable ASCII escaped, then the delimiter can just be a newline (at which point you’re using JSONlines as your protocol), and the Python code can use `makefile` on the socket and call `readline` instead of looping over `recv`.
- Cheat and use JSON as if it were a framed protocol. It isn’t, but as long as the only top-level values you ever send are objects and arrays, it works. Then the Python code can use `raw_decode` (see the `json` module docs) after each receive until it succeeds.
- If you’re only ever going to send a single message, you can just half-shutdown the socket (close the write end) from Java, and then Python will get its EOF and respond on the still-open other side of the socket. (This may sound hacky, but it’s actually perfectly common—it’s how web browsers traditionally work, although HTTP 1.1 made things a bit more complicated.)

Answer (score 0):

Your response is not a line, as it doesn't seem to contain a line ending.
That means it `readLine` will read forever.

Try adding a newline to your response to make `readLine` happy:

```
resp = "Prova\n"
```